# How to redirect author subdomain pages to each author pages on www

Tags: multisite, redirect, author, multi-author

I need to redirect author subdomain pages, for example: 
http://www.studionews24.com/author/author-name/

I noticed that if I'm on a specific subdomain URL like http://calcio.studionews24.com/chiuso-il-calciomercato-di-riparazione-2014/ if I click on author_posts_link it redirects me to http://calcio.studionews24.com/author/tommaso-giacomelli/
and not to the specific author that I can find at http://www.studionews24.com/author/tommaso-giacomelli/

So, for now I have chosen to redirect all author subdomain pages to this static page:
http://www.studionews24.com/redazione/

The only author_posts_link that works correctly is the one on the main domain.

**How can I redirect all author pages to the main domain (www.)?**

Comment: Looking at the links it seems as if you managed to solve your problem. Would you mind sharing your solution?

Comment: Yes, i have made an htacces redirection with the unique www. template directory. But i think it could works fine also with the plugin wp redirection.